# SVN: Global and project-specific passwd files for single repository

Tags: security, svn, passwd

I would like to configure my local SVN server to support both a global passwd file and a project specific passwd file.

I have a global passwd file set up that is currently used to administer all accounts. The only problem is, sometimes we want to an outside developer to a single project. With our current setup, we have to grant them access to all accounts.

The ideal solution would be a global passwd file for all in-house developers, as well as a project-specific passwd file for outside developers working on one project only.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up [path based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) or [per-directory access control](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir).

Comment: +1, it's much better to use access control instead of meddling with account password files.